# MySQL Correlated Subquery (with multiple columns) per row

Tags: mysql, subquery

MySQL documentation states that:

> Subqueries in the FROM clause cannot be correlated subqueries. They
>   are materialized in whole (evaluated to produce a result set) during
>   query execution, so they cannot be evaluated per row of the outer
>   query.

Okay, fine, I understand why this is. However, what if you want to repeat a specific query on multiple values?

```
SELECT COUNT( returning_visitors.per_ip ) AS count, AVG( returning_visitors.per_ip ) AS num_visits
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS per_ip
    FROM site_hits_unique
    WHERE site_hits_unique.site_id = ___INPUT___
    AND site_hits_unique.date >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    GROUP BY site_hits_unique.site_id, site_hits_unique.ip
    HAVING per_ip >1
) AS returning_visitors
```

Let's say I want to retrieve the result of this query on multiple values in the form of a result table, using the values from `SELECT id FROM sites`. Is there a way to do this in a single query without using a stored procedure? Something like:

```
SELECT id, COUNT( returning_visitors.per_ip ) as readers, AVG( returning_visitors.per_ip ) as avg_visits_pr
FROM sites
SUBQUERY-PER-ROW (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS per_ip
    FROM site_hits_unique
    WHERE site_hits_unique.site_id = sites.id
    AND site_hits_unique.date >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    GROUP BY site_hits_unique.site_id, site_hits_unique.ip
    HAVING per_ip > 1
) AS returning_visitors
WHERE sites.id IN (162888, 42705, 11412)
```

`SUBQUERY-PER-ROW` here is pseudo-code. `JOIN` will not work because of the above quoted restriction.

EDIT:

Another attempt at pseudo-code using info from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-subqueries.html:

```
SELECT id, (
    SELECT COUNT( per_ip ) AS count, AVG( per_ip ) AS num_visits
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT( * ) AS per_ip
        FROM site_hits_unique
        WHERE site_hits_unique.site_id = sites.id
        AND site_hits_unique.date >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
        GROUP BY site_hits_unique.site_id, site_hits_unique.ip
        HAVING per_ip >1
    ) AS returning_visitors
) as (readers, avg_visits_pr)
FROM sites
WHERE sites.id IN (162888, 42705, 11412)
```

(it doesn't work, this isn't actual valid MySQL syntax, just a pseudo-code example)

Comment: Please!  Qualify the column names so we can know which table each belongs to.

Comment: Done...................

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT  s.id,
        COUNT( rv.per_ip ) as readers,
        AVG( rv.per_ip ) as avg_visits_pr
    FROM  sites AS s
    JOIN  
    (
        SELECT  u.site_id,
                COUNT( * ) AS per_ip
            FROM  site_hits_unique AS u
            WHERE  u.date >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
            GROUP BY  u.site_id, u.ip
            HAVING  per_ip > 1 
    )  AS rv ON rv.site_id = s.id
    WHERE  s.id IN (162888, 42705, 11412)
```

Indexes:

```
site_hits_unique: INDEX(site_id, date, ip)
```

Or maybe this:

```
SELECT  site_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as readers,
        COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as avg_visits_pr
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  site_id, ip, COUNT(*) AS per_ip
            FROM  site_hits_unique
            WHERE  date >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
              AND  site_id IN (162888, 42705, 11412)
            GROUP BY  site_id, ip
            HAVING  per_ip > 1 
    ) AS rv
    GROUP BY  site_id;
```

Comment: Both technically work, but due to the size of site_hits_unique for performance reasons I'd like to restrict the subquery to only focus on one site_id at a time. The temporary table generated by ANY site_id is humongous. Am I correct in thinking that the subquery dealing with one site_id at a time will consume less system resources and perform faster?

Comment: I would suggest [_Uniques Summary Table_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/rollup-unique-user-counts/) , but `HAVING  per_ip > 1` prevents use of it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I discovered a way to accomplish what I wanted to accomplish using stored procedures. I'm hoping this isn't the only solution and that there is a way to do this with a single query, but here's what I've got.

Stored procedure to get returning readers on a single site_id:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE get_site_readers(
    IN input_site_id INT,
    OUT readers INT,
    OUT avg_visits_pr DOUBLE)
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT( per_ip ), AVG( per_ip )
    INTO readers, avg_visits_pr
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT( * ) AS per_ip
        FROM site_hits_unique
        WHERE site_id = input_site_id
        AND date >= CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
        GROUP BY site_id, ip
        HAVING per_ip > 1
    ) AS returning_visitors;

END
```

Stored procedure to run get_site_readers(...) on every sites.id:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE update_site_readers() BEGIN
    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE _id BIGINT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM sites;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

    OPEN cur;

    eachSite: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO _id;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE eachSite;
        END IF;
        CALL get_site_readers(_id, @readers, @avg_visits_pr);
        UPDATE sites SET readers = @readers, avg_visits_pr = @avg_visits_pr WHERE id=_id;
    END LOOP eachSite;

    CLOSE cur;
END
```

Notice the query `UPDATE sites SET readers = @readers, avg_visits_pr = @avg_visits_pr WHERE id=_id;` - this was my intention from the beginning, to update the sites table with the aggregated data. However, this does not exactly solve the question as defined since originally I was asking about doing a `SELECT`.

Finally, to call the stored procedure:

```
CALL update_site_readers();
```